# create button dynamically by javascript and show variable content on click

Tags: javascript

I am creating button like this:

```
    if(this.error_msg) {
        let btn_err = document.createElement('button');
        btn_err.type = "button";
        btn_err.name = "add";
        btn_err.textContent = "Remove";
        btn_err.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary btn-sm");

        btn_wrapper.append(btn_err);

        toastBody.append(btn_wrapper);
    }
```

How can I show `this.error_msg` on button click as alert?

Comment: add an event listener to the button to call the alert

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener to the button using javascript.

```
btn_err.onclick = function(){alert(this.error_msg)}
```

Comment: I can´t access ```this.error_msg``` in the function. Should I declare a variable one line before?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

*Note: I have changed if argument as true since you did not share your whole code, it is just to show working example*

```js
const testFunction = () => {
  if(true) {
          let btn_err = document.createElement('button');
          btn_err.type = "button";
          btn_err.name = "add";
          btn_err.textContent = "Remove";
          btn_err.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary btn-sm");
          btn_err.onclick = function(){alert("Error message")}
          let btn_wrapper = document.getElementById("buttonWrapper")
          btn_wrapper.append(btn_err);
      }    
 }
 testFunction();
```

```html
<div id="buttonWrapper">

</div>
```